# Save location - Files from Python open and write functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, onedrive

I am trying to sync files from "One Drive" to my own desktop.

I am using the following code piece to download files from One drive to desktop:

```py
if response.status_code == 200:
    print('\n> Response Success')

    with open('Book2.xlsx', 'wb') as File:
        File.write(response.content)
        
        #print(File(type))
        #df = pd.DataFrame(File)
        #print(df)
        
        #df.to_excel(r'C:\Users\s.gaur\Desktop\Test.xlsx')
        
        print('\n> File Downloaded')
else:
    print('\n> Failed:', response.status_code)
    print(response.content)
```

The file is getting downloaded, but I am not able to understand, where to find the file on my local computer. Please help me where it would be located if it's coming from sync from One Drive.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

usually files get saved to the parent directory of the script you can run

```
import os
os.getcwd()
```

to get the parent dir.
you can also use absolute paths in your file pointer creation statement
i.e

```
with open('/tmp/Book2.xlsx', 'wb') as File:
```

then it's obvious it's saving it to /tmp/Book2.xlsx

in windows you need to use \
or use os.path.join functionality i.e

```
os.path.join('tmp','Book2.xlsx')
```

gl hf